# Send emails on Google form submission using specific variables

Tags: javascript, forms, google-sheets, google-forms

I am really new with this of Google scripts and I need your help.

I have a form that among the fields it has, it has one field named owner this is just a name.

I need to create a script to send a notification to the person that is listed in the owner field when the form is submitted.

I know how to burn an email directly on the script

```
function myFunction() {
  // Fetch the email address
  var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Test").getRange("B2");
var emailAddress = emailRange.getValues();
// Send Alert Email.
var message = 'This is your Alert email!'; // Second column
var subject = 'Your Google Spreadsheet Alert';
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
}
```

The problem I am lost with is that I know how to recognize the email depending on the name of the owner which is stored in another sheet.

[Here](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdbFzl-Xfzs1Bl5XYOfp6Vvx1RxAlImTgUYdSkMVRc6XLlTwg/viewform) is the link of a sample form and [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13eXooWHZLWvR4F0aYyRt1r3E859xcVDItU1bFzXjUig/edit#gid=1787761824) is the sample spreadsheet

Can anyone share some light?

Answer (score 0):

There are four things for you to understand and research.

1 - Create a script that can be created as an Installable "OnFormSubmit" trigger. [Documentation is here.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_sheets_events). This will execute every time a form is submitted. This is easy to do, and I have added a screenshot of the add trigger screen at the end of this answer.

2 - Learn about the information captured by an "OnFormSubmit" script. In particular it will return the range of the form submission from which you want the value of Column 7 (the Owner).

3 - The emails sheet contains a separate set of data. You can get it by referencing it with `getSheetByName` - [documentation Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename)

4 - You need to look for a match between "Owner and the "Name" value on the "Emails" sheet. There are many options for how to find a match with the owner but looping through the "emails" data is probably the easiest. At each new line you check whether the email name is a match for the "Owner". When you find a match, then you get the accompanying email address (in the cell beside the email name). Then you can send the email as you tested.

---

This code adapts your existing code to work through the steps mentioned.

```
function so5524531901(e) {

  // this script as an Installable "OnFormSubmit" Trigger

  //setup the spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  //get the range from OnFormSubmit
  var range = e.range;
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: the range is "+range.getA1Notation());//DEBUG

  // get the data for the range
  var response = range.getValues();

  // get the owner name from the form submission
  var owner = response[0][7];
  Logger.log("DEBUG: Owner = "+owner);// DEBUG

  // get the emails list
  var emailSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Emails");
  // get ALL the data from this sheet
  var emaildata = emailSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  // check how many rows of data
  var emailLastRow = emailSheet.getLastRow();
  // start the loop through the emails data
  for (var i=1; i<emailLastRow; i++){

    // if owner is equal to Email Name
    if (owner == emaildata[i][0]){
      // there is a match
      //get the email address
      var emailAddress = emaildata[i][1];
      Logger.log("DEBUG: owner = "+emaildata[i][0]+", email address: "+emailAddress);// DEBUG

      // Send Alert Email.
      // Uncomment the following rows to declare the message, subject and then send the email.
      // var message = 'This is your Alert email!'; // Second column
      //var subject = 'Your Google Spreadsheet Alert';
      //MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);

    }
  }
}
```

---

[image: Create an Installable Trigger for OnFormSubmit]